# How to utilize a function defined in another component in other components in React

Tags: reactjs, components

I have a component A

```
export default const A = () => {
    const GetItemX = () => {
        alert("Devine calling);
    }

    const GetItemY = () => {
        alert("Another function in this component");
    }
}
```

And another component B

```
export default const B = () => {
    const callGetItemX = getItemX();
    }
}
```

How would I get the function `getItemX` to work inside component B?

Comment: you can define `GetItemX` outside in one separate file and import in both components, but your function should not be using the state variables of the components themselves.

Comment: GetItemX uses state variables in that component where it is defined.

Comment: You can pass the `getItemX` function as a `prop` to `B` if it is a nested component or use the Context API to declare the `getItemX` function globally and retrieve it in both components using the `useContext` hook